# Connecting from a container to localhost

Tags: docker

I'm running a web service on `http://localhost:8000`, where I want to connect from a docker container. So basically inside the docker container I've tried

- `requests.get("http//:localhost:8000)`
- `requests.get("http//:host.docker.internal:8000)`
- `requests.get("http//:0.0.0.0:8000)`

but all these give an

```
equivalent error: **requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=8000): Max
retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x7f95892fdbb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2]
Name or service not known'))**
```

Comment: Im running docker via docker-compose up and this how my docker-compose.yml looks like https://imgur.com/a/D51rASd

Comment: Which docker version are you running? Also can you share the Dockerfile for the `test` container? The correct way to get to the host from a docker container is to point to `host.docker.internal`

Comment: `localhost` from the container is the container, not your host machine. Put your WS in a docker container and put the 2 in a Docker network, or use host networking.

Comment: Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
 dockerfile: https://imgur.com/a/lzPxiXC

Comment: @AymDev Ive added the "extra_hosts:  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"" to the docker-compose.yml, but it doesnt have any affect.

Comment: i solved the issue by replacing  "host-gateway" by my machines local ip in the  "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"